# PHP namespace calling functions from different directories

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to get php's namespace technique down but having some issues here:

Why can I not call the method testA from class B? Also I would like to add that I am using 5.3.

in lib ->

```
<?php
namespace lib;

class A{

        public static function testA(){

                  echo "I am inside A";
        }
 }
```

in root dir ->

```
<?php

class B{

    public function showSomething(){
               lib\A::testA();
    } 

 $test = new B();
 $test->showSomething();
```

Comment: have you included the lib\a.php file in b.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're including the file that holds your class A.

Answer (score 1):

Using namespace you only encapsulate item but not include it. I can't see including of the class file. Include it or use [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).